# How to add configurations to user to a VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to add a simple configuration to my VSCode extension, but I can't find the correct information.

I just want that the user have a string input field, that has a default value, and read it from my typescript code through the vscode library

Can someone provide me and example about which file should I add, where, and how to consume? also if more configurations are needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found

I need to add into my package.json

```js
...
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      ...
    ],
    "configuration": {
      "title": "My Extension",
      "properties": {
        "myExtension.myProperty": {
          "type": "string",
          "default": "default",
          "description": "description"
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

and consume

```js
vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('myExtension').myProperty;
```

Comment: I think I don't need that settings.json, why is it needed?

Comment: why add a configuration when it is the same for every user

Comment: ? It's not the same, that proprty can be changed by the user depending it's needs

Comment: Any idea @Víctor How to add a new configuration when we want to create a launch.json file?